# In asp.net mvc what is the difference in using "new" and not using "new" in select query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two queries as follows:

- `Select(a => a.IsAdmin)`
- `Select(x => new {x.IsAdmin})`

... and I have two questions:

- What is the difference between the two?
- When should we use and when shouldn't we use the keyword, 'new'?

Comment: The first will return the current value of `IsAdmin` based on the object being evaluated. The second instantiates a new object of `IsAdmin` and will return it's default value.

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
   Select(a => a.IsAdmin)
```

will return `IEnumerable<bool>` (assuming that the property IsAdmin is of `bool` type)

The statement

```
Select(x => new {x.IsAdmin})
```

on the other hand, will return an `IEnumerable<*anonymous type*>` where the objects will have an anonymous type with the property `IsAdmin` of type `bool`

Comment: Almost. The latter returns `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is that anonymous type.

Comment: Well, I thought a bit about how to write it...It isn't really T because the type is known; it is not a "template" type. Do you think writing T instead of object might be clearer?

Comment: I changed it from object to *anonymous type*

Comment: Looks good to me. It matters because you want the compiler to know that the items in the result have properties named `IsAdmin` that can be freely accessed. With `IEnumerable<object>`, you wouldn't have that.

Comment: I think in C#7 you will be able to write `IEnumerable<(bool IsAdmin)>` with the new C# Tuples https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/01/20/new-features-in-c-sharp-7/

Answer (score 4):

Consider that the latter is effectively the equivalent of doing this for each item:

```
var output = new { input.IsAdmin };
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var output = new { IsAdmin = input.IsAdmin };
```

Since the target property name for `IsAdmin` is inferred from the source when not specified. So...

```
items.Select(a => a.IsAdmin)
```

This returns an enumerable of `bool` - where each item is the value of `IsAdmin` of an element in `items`.

Sample return value: `[True, False, True, True, False]`.

```
items.Select(a => new {a.IsAdmin})
```

This returns an enumerable of *anonymous objects*, where each object has an `IsAdmin` property whose value is that of the corresponding `IsAdmin` property of an item in `items`.

Sample return value: `[{ IsAdmin: True }, { IsAdmin: False }, ...]`.

Which to use when is at your discretion - typically you'd use the latter when you want to return multiple properties for each item, rather than a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply think,

In the first statement your are simply returning a list of native data type. Like it may be int,bool,string depends on your IsAdmin type.

And in the second one you are creating an anonymous type object with property IsAdmin and returning this collection.